# Auto fill a column with formulas when new rows are added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an automation workflow (Zapier) which adds a new row to a Google Sheets whenever a new card is added in Trello. We use it to track statistics for departments etc. I have some extra fields which transform a date field into things like weeknumber, day, month, year... simple stuff.

I need to write a script which looks out for new rows entered into the spreadsheet and then auto-fills the other columns with preset formulas.

Example layout:

Columns populated via the automation:

```
a,b,d,e
```

Columns to populate via the script.

```
f,g,h,i,j,k
```

I've seen a few scripts that are similar but don't take a formula from the row above as the content to autofill.

Note: The formulas for each column are available in the row above which has been added manually by me (for now). So, in theory, the script could reference the cell above for the correct formula to use.

Note 2: I cannot use the ARRAYFORMULA method because Zapier will see the row as having content and will skip to the next empty row.

Comment: I apologize for rejecting your change.  I thought the copy would get values.  But if it does get formulas like Michelle says then it is probably the better approach because it preserves cell references.  Thanks this has been a learning experience for me.

Comment: Don't worry about it! Team learning yields results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it.

```
function fillInFGHIJK()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!vA[i][5] && !vA[i][6] && !vA[i][7] && !vA[i][8] && !vA[i][9] && !vA[i][10])
    {
      sh.getRange(i,6,1,6).copyTo(sh.getRange(i+1,6,1,6));//According to Michelle this will works better because the cell references change appropriately
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's pulling through the value of the cell before, can it pull through the formula?

Comment: I changed the answer try it again

Comment: What will happen to cell references when formulas are duplicated in this way? I suggest using `copyTo` method instead, `sh.getRange(i,6,1,6).copyTo(sh.getRange(i+1,6,1,6))`. It's equivalent to manual copying, which does the expected thing with formulas. As an added bonus, if some columns contain values (to be used as formula parameters), they will be copied too.

Comment: Ah yeah, thank you @Michelle and Cooper – A combination of both your scripts has worked for me. The copyTo function means that it references the correct row. Thanks team!

Comment: I thought the copy would get the values rather than the formulas.  But I'm not sure.  If you say so, I believe you.  I don't really use formulas very often.  Oh I finally see the issue.  In my version the cell references will be wrong.  Well hopefully your version will get the formulas and not the values.  I'll have to try that sometime @Michelle thanks.  Sorry to reject the edit.  I didn't understand at the time.