# Auto fill a column in Google Sheets with formula when new row is added (without arrayformula)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Similar to [Auto fill a column in Google Sheets with formulas when new rows are added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738468/auto-fill-a-column-in-google-sheets-with-formulas-when-new-rows-are-added) where I have a Zapier that auto-populates a specific worksheet in a google sheet.
I have Columns A through F. The F column has an associated formula to it (referencing the C column in the same row) that I'd like to have applied when a new row is auto-generated above it.

Note: I can't use arrayformula because Zapier will assume that the row has content and will open a new row above it

Example of google sheet

   `A       B       C        D    E      F        G
1  Name    Email   Lecture Date  Quiz  Score    Code 
2  Neil    foo@bar 2       5/5   4     Pass     (formula ref C2)
3  Rose    bar@foo 10      4/5   5     Failed   (formula ref C3)`

Comment: Second sheet with `=query`. Or update your zapier method to write the formulas you need too. Or run a time based trigger (since programmatic edits do not necessarily trigger spreadsheet events) to add it

Comment: @tehhowch if I update the zapier method which adds a new line to the spreadsheet (which I don't know what will be yet and references a different column in said row) how do I write the formula for this soon-to-be row ?

Comment: Use R1C1 referencing & `INDIRECT` (to parse the reference to a range). An internet search should teach you the rest of what you need to know about R1C1.